# Problem with limit rendering items in Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I can't limit the number of rendering per batch in Flatlist.

here is the code:

```
<FlatList 
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            initialNumToRender={5}
            windowSize={5}
            data={twitch.data}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
        {Data}
            )}/>
```

By default it loads 20 items.

Comment: data={twitch.data.slice(0, 20)} try this and replace 20 with your limit.

Comment: thanks @AhsanAbrar and how to update or refresh it? like when user reach the end of list?

Comment: I think you are talking about pagination and  in general frontend and backend both are involved to achieve the pagination

Comment: @AhsanAbrar i know but with slice() it won't work